# How can I access a list from a controller in JavaScript?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to access a list in a JavaScript (on a JSP page) the list is defined in my controller:

```
model.addAttribute("listeventfuture", this.Evennementervice.findAllFuture());
```

In the JSP page I have this:

```
events: { "2013-04-30": {"number": 5, "url": "http://w3widgets.comresponsive-slider"}
    }
```

How can I fill `events` list from `listeventfuture`?

Comment: Looks like a near-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355593/spring-mvc-addattribute-to-model-how-to-get-it-from-jsp-javascript

Comment: Thank you so much kryger  that post really helped.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to include the eventual answer, you can add your own answer and mark this question as "solved".

Comment: Can you tell me how ? I'm new here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was

```
  var showVar = '<c:out value="${listeventfuture}"/>';
```